# Google Analytics: setting _trackPageview onLoad

Tags: javascript, analytics

Does anyone know why this:

```
    $('document').ready(function(){
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/my-custom-url']);
    });
```

..wouldn't get picked up by GA?

We have an embedded service which displays different states of a page (same URL), depending on where the user is in the journey - hence the need to set a custom URL for each phase.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine but without knowing your domain and seeing the GA set up script it's hard to guess.

I'd suggest installing the [Google Analytics Debugger Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna). This might let you know if the gaq had any issues getting setup.

Comment: Thanks, David! Will give that a whirl.